# Is it possible to move files from Backblaze B2 to Amazon S3 without downloading them?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud-storage

Is it possible to move files from Backblaze B2 to Amazon S3 without downloading them? And then to go back again?

We have 4.7TB of data which needs to be duplicated, and B2 doesn't have a copy function.

Answer (score 0):

[I managed to do this using ForkLift for Mac](https://binarynights.com/)

I used the free trial and it worked great! I was able to just drag and drop the files from the B2 to the S3 as simple as that!