# Is it possible to use the command line to transfer data from Backblaze B2 to Amazon S3 without downloading to a local directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backblaze

I would like to move files from Backblaze B2 to Amazon S3. The [instructions here](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047779633-Quickstart-Guide-for-AWS-CLI-and-Backblaze-B2-Cloud-Storage) say that I should download them to a local directory. However, I am trying to transfer about 180 TB of data so I would prefer to not have to download them locally.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218476/is-it-possible-to-move-files-from-backblaze-b2-to-amazon-s3-without-downloading) with a similar question, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using the command line instead of ForkLift.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). The `aws s3 cp` command can read `stdin` or write to `stdout` by using `-` instead of a filename, so you can pipe two `aws s3 cp` commands together to read a file from Backblaze B2 and write it to Amazon S3 without it hitting the local disk.

First, configure two AWS profiles from the command line - one for B2 and the other for AWS. `aws configure` will prompt you for the credentials for each account:

```shell
% aws configure --profile b2
% aws configure --profile aws
```

After you run `aws configure`, edit the AWS config file (`~/.aws/config` on Mac and Linux, `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config` on Windows) and add a value for `endpoint_url` to the `b2` profile. This saves you from having to specify the `--endpoint-url` option every time you run `aws s3` with the `b2` profile.

For example, if your B2 region was `us-west-004` and your AWS region was `us-west-1`, you would edit your config file to look like this:

```
[profile b2]
region = us-west-004
endpoint_url = https://s3.us-west-004.backblazeb2.com

[profile aws]
region = us-west-1
```

Now you can specify the profiles in the two `aws s3 cp` commands.

```bash
aws --profile b2 s3 cp s3://<Your Backblaze bucket name>/filename.ext - \
| aws --profile aws s3 cp - s3://<Your AWS bucket name>/filename.ext
```

It's easy to run a quick test on a single file

```shell
# Write a file to Backblaze B2
% echo 'Hello world!' | \
aws --profile b2 s3 cp - s3://metadaddy-b2/hello.txt

# Copy file from Backblaze B2 to Amazon S3
% aws --profile b2 s3 cp s3://metadaddy-b2/hello.txt - \
| aws --profile aws s3 cp - s3://metadaddy-s3/hello.txt

# Read the file from Amazon S3
% aws --profile aws s3 cp s3://metadaddy-s3/hello.txt -
Hello world!
```

One wrinkle is that, if the file is more than 50 GB, you will need to use the `--expected-size` argument to specify the file size so that the `cp` command can split the stream into parts for a large file upload. From the [AWS CLI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html):

> `--expected-size` (string) This argument specifies the expected size of a stream in terms of bytes. Note that this argument is needed only when a stream is being uploaded to s3 and the size is larger than 50GB. Failure to include this argument under these conditions may result in a failed upload due to too many parts in upload.

Here's a one-liner that copies the contents of a bucket on B2 to a bucket on S3, outputting the filename (object key) and size of each file. It assumes you've set up the profiles as above.

```bash
aws --profile b2 s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket metadaddy-b2 \
| jq '.Contents[] | .Key, .Size' \
| xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo "Copying \"$1\" ($2 bytes)"; \
    aws --profile b2 s3 cp "s3://metadaddy-b2/$1" - \
    | aws s3 --profile aws cp - "s3://metadaddy-s3/$1" --expected-size $2' sh
```

Although this technique does not hit the local disk, the data still has to flow from B2 to wherever this script is running, then to S3. As [@Mark B mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76157276/33905), run the script on an EC2 instance for best performance.